# Running tests by filtering with grep not working

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have the following tests:

```
test('111', async t => {
    await t.expect(true).ok()
});

test('222', async t => {
    await t.expect(true).ok()
});
```

I would like to run both tests using [-T , --test-grep](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/command-line-interface.html#-t-pattern---test-grep-pattern) pattern, however when executing in the powershell I'm getting an error:

```
npx testcafe -T "111|222"

'222' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Why is this happening? I'm sure I'm using the correct regex pattern.
Also I don't want to make use of test [metadata](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/command-line-interface.html#--test-meta-keyvaluekey2value2) filtering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a look at this issue https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/4615
It looks like npx has problems with regex parsing and also the -T parameter.

I executed `node_modules\.bin\testcafe --test-grep '111|222'` and it worked!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the TestCafe argument parser cannot parse the grep string correctly in this case.
Please wrap your `grep` argument in single quotes as follows:

```
testcafe chrome test.js -T '"111|222"'
```

Comment: Oh I took a look at this issue https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/4615